# Why are columns not included in the result set required in a group by?

Tags: sql

Consider the following contrived SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT e.job_title,
       CASE WHEN e.is_full_time = 'Y' THEN e.name || ' full time' ELSE e.name || ' part time' END,
       SUM(c.monterary_value)
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN car c ON c.employee_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.job_title,
         e.is_full_time,
         e.name;
```

Why is `e.is_full_time` required, given that the group by will aggregate based on the results and not the check?

Comment: The result of the CASE depends on both `e.name` and `e.is_full_time`, there might be two rows with the same name but different `Y`/`N`.

Comment: `e.is_full_time` is included in the result-set in the same way that `e.name` is included - as part of an expression.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for that, it's seems obvious now that you've explained it. If you would like to formalise your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose in your data you have two records with the same name but different `is_full_time` values - which one should be evaluated in the select clause?  To avoid any chance of ambguity or presumption, all expressions in the `SELECT` must either me in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregation.  *Some* systems will be a little more flexible and pick, say, the *first* results in a group, or pick one arbitrarily, but most enterprise-level databases enforce this requirement.

One way to avoid having an unnecessary `GROUP BY` expression is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT e.job_title,
       CASE WHEN e.is_full_time = 'Y' THEN e.name || ' full time' ELSE e.name || ' part time' END,
       c.monterary_value
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT employee_id, SUM(monterary_value) monterary_value 
    FROM car  
    GROUP BY employee_id ) c
  ON c.employee_id = e.id
```

Comment: Afaik there's only a single *some systems*, MySQL :-)

Comment: @dnoeth FoxPro does too :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL executes `GROUP BY` before `SELECT`, so if it sees a non-aggregated column in the `SELECT` clause which wasn't in the `GROUP BY` clause then it complains.